# Change Codelens Scope in VSCode

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode a lot to develop various Powershell Scripts. All scripts are organized in a single git project.

So my question is: Is it possible to limit the scope of codelens to only a single file?

Currently codelens counts the references to a function in all files in a project. Most of my scripts consist of only one file and i want to count the references only within **one** file only.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any configuration options for the CodeLens within Code itself. However you can see the references how many times in that file a function was used, it shows you in the "pop-up window":

[image]

I just added an internal function `Get-RemoteIntegrationService` that is called in the `Copy-DbaSsisCatalog.ps1` file two times and then it is also called in another file. So the side bar shows me it is referenced two times within the file I have opened.